# complex vector pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, unordered-map

`vector <unordered_map <string, DomainInfo *> *> victimDomains;`

What does this mean?

I got the first star (`DomainInfo*`) but what is the second one?

Lets say `DomainInfo` has two properties `ID` and `name`. If I want to bring the second element in `DomainInfo` of third `unordered_map` in `victimDomains` how could I call it?
is my question not correct?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In plain english, it is a `vector` of pointers to (`unordered_map`s mapping `string`s to pointers of `DomainInfo`). (using brackets to indicate levels)

You want to do

```
(*victimDomains[2])[<domainInfoKey>]->name;
 ^B             ^A    ^C                ^D
```

A - 2nd Element - a pointer to the map.
B - Dereference the pointer to the map to get a map.
C - Get the  `DomainInfo` pointer (need to enter the correct string)
D - Use -> syntax to access the name field from the `DomainInfo` pointer.

---

Above in multiple steps -

```
unordered_map <string, DomainInfo *> *map = victimDomains[2];

DomainInfo *dmInfo = *map[<domainInfoKey>];

Name name = dmInfo->name;
```

Comment: I think it is better not to go that deep

Comment: @tusherity yup, it could get quite confusing, you can take it in steps, but the depth will have to be traversed either in steps or in one shot.

Comment: without writing code & getting outputs, I dont think my brain would want to understand it, but thanks for help

Comment: @tusherity I have written it out in 3 steps if that helps

Answer (score 1):

To access a particular `DomainInfo`, you need to know its key in the `unoreder_map`. So exactly as it stands, your question (how to access?) cannot be answered. However, if you knew the `DomainInfo`'s key was, let's say, `"blah"`, then you would do:

```
(*victimDomains[2])["blah"]->name
```